# foreign key in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a model for musics and a model for comment of musics:

```
class music(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    STATUS_CHOICES = (('draft', 'Draft'), ('published', 'Published'),)
    music = models.FileField()
    music_image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    singer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    music_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text_of_music = models.TextField()
    create = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True)
   update = models.DateField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)
    publish = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, blank=True, null=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    objects = models.Manager()
    published = PublishedManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-publish',)


    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('music:music_detail',
                   kwargs={"id":self.id})


class comment(models.Model):
    # Foreignkey for each music
    For = models.ForeignKey(music, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='post')
    body = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    commented_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and this is my view:

```
def music_Detail(request, id=None):
    user = request.user
    template_name = 'music/music_detail.html'
    Music = music.objects.all().filter(id=id)
    new_comment = None
    Comment = comment.objects.all().filter(active=True)
    form = comment_form(data=request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
            new_comment.For = Music
            new_comment.save()
        form = comment_form()
    return render(request, template_name, {'Music': Music, 'Comment': Comment, 'form': form})
```

Well, I get this error when I comment:

```
Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<music: m, majid kharatha>]>": "comment.For" must be a "music" instance.
```

How can I solve this problem and how can I display the information of the user who left this comment?

Comment: In Django, you should name your models in `PascalCase` and instances and fields thereof in `snake_case`. Right now you're mixing and matching...

Comment: I will fixed it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, you'll have to assign a single `Music`, not a queryset.

Instead of [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#filter)ing to get a new queryset containing a single music,

```
Music = music.objects.all().filter(id=id)
```

you want to [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get) a single one:

```
Music = music.objects.get(id=id)
```

Comment: thank you, You know, at first, when I did this, it didn't work because I had for loop on this object in the template, but now I added another field in the view with Get to comment.

Comment: how can I get user information who created this comment and show it with comment?